# Using node.js express res object to send data to client into HTML client script tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

I am wondering if there is any way at all that you can use a res object in node.js express to send data to the client but apart from is there a way to send the data from the res object DIRECTLY to the script tag on the client. The problem I have is that the only way I have been shown to send data to a client is by sending it directly to the HTML code of the client like this:

server side:

```
app.get("/", (req, res)=>
{
    send_item = {new_client:true, user: null}

    res.render("index", {send_item});

}
```

client side:

```
<%=send_item%>
```

I find this very inefficent and I wish there was a more simple way of just referencing the `<%=send_item%>` in javascript or even make the res.render send the data directly to the script area on the client-side in the `<script>`  tags

Comment: you'd need to call for the data from the `script` tag in you view with `Ajax` for example. then in your route you could just send a [json or a jsonp](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json) response.

Comment: @fedesc I am not very fimiliar with Ajax nor jsonp